What is the distinction between διδάσκαλος and καθηγητὴς as used in Matthew 23:8-10?

“But you are not to be called rabbi, for you have one teacher
[didaskalos, SG1320], and you are all brothers. And call no man your
father on earth, for you have one Father, who is in heaven. Neither be
called instructors, for you have one instructor [kathégétés,
SG2519], the Christ." - Matthew 23:8-10 ESV

The BDAG defines both διδάσκαλος and καθηγητὴς as "teacher" and various English translations choose various synonyms (the glosses in Strong's Greek are also similar).
Are these true synonyms in ancient Greek or do they have specific nuances that make these two words slightly different?

There is no question that διδάσκαλος and καθηγητὴς are close synonyms.  Both can be translated as "teacher", or "instructor", or even "master".  BDAG confirms that as the OP correctly states.
However, there is a very slight difference in emphasis in the meaning:

διδάσκαλος is simply teacher in the sense of the "jug to mug" model of teaching.
καθηγητὴς is a more nuanced idea of teaching because it is a compound word from two others: κατά (an intensifier here) + ἡγέομαι (to lead or guide).  Thus, the meaning includes "teaching" in the usual sense but also includes moral guidance and might be said to include "mentoring" with overtones of "encouraging" and "training".

This latter meaning is consistent with the all-pervasive NT teaching of Jesus as our example in all things.  See appendix below.
APPENDIX: The Imitation of Christ
The Imitation of Christ is one of the central parts of the plan of salvation.  Essentially, the Bible tells converted Christians that they must behave in the same way as Jesus did.  Indeed, Jesus’ final instruction to His disciples was to make more disciples (Matt 28:19) – disciples were imitators of their masters and thus became like their teachers (Luke 6:40).
Here is a sample of the huge amount of material available on this subject.

Walk as Jesus walked.  1 John 2:6.
Jesus was led by the Spirit Matt 4:1.  The Christian must be born of the Spirit (John 3:5) by receiving the gift of the Spirit (Acts 2:38) and walk by the Spirit (Gal 5:25, John 6:63, Phil 3:3, John 4:24).  In fact, the whole life of Christian is to put aside the “psychical” mind and live by the Spirit (1 Cor 2:14, 1 Cor 15:44-46, Gal 5:17, Jude 19, John 6:63, 1 Peter 3:18).
Love as Jesus loved.  John 13:34, 35, 15:12, 1 John 4:8, 11, 19, Eph 5:1, 2.
Lay down life for friends.  John 15:13, Eph 5:2.
Jesus’ suffering leaves us an example.  John 16:33, 1 Cor 7:28, 2 Tim 1:4, Heb 13:12, 13, 1 Peter 2:21, 4:14, 5:8, 9.
Because Jesus was persecuted, so are His followers.  John 15:20, 21.
Conformed to the likeness of the Son.  Rom 8:29.
Transforming our will and bodies to conform to God’s will.  Rom 12:1, 2.
Jesus was baptized (Matt 3:13-17, Mark 1:9-11, Luke 3:21, 22) and so should we be baptized, Matt 28:19, Acts 2:38, 10:48, 16:31, 22:16, Rom 6:1-9, etc.
Forgive as Jesus forgave.  Matt 6:12, 14, 15, 18:35, Eph 4:32, Col 3:13.
Be holy as Jesus is holy.  Lev 11:44, 45, 1 Peter 1:15, 16.
Be pure as He is pure.  1 John 3:3.
Partakers of the divine nature.  2 Peter 1:4.
We are being changed into Christ’s glory (= reputation).  2 Cor 3:18.
Pray as Jesus prayed. Luke 11:1. See also the many instances where Jesus prayed earnestly such as Heb 5:7, Matt 14:23, 26:36, 39, 42, 44, Mark 1:35, Luke 3:21, 5:16, 6:12, 9:18, 11:1, 22:32, 41-46, John 17, etc.
We are to have the mind of Christ.  Phil 2:5, 1 Cor 2:16.
Be kind because God is kind.  Luke 6:34, 35.
Be merciful because God is merciful.  Luke 6:36.
Be servants to others as Jesus was.  John 13:15-17, 1 Peter 4:11b, Matt 20:24-28.
Be patient as Jesus was patient.  1 Tim 1:16.
Talk/speak as Jesus speaks.  1 Peter 4:11a.
Be “perfect” (= mature and generous to enemies) as the Father is.  Matt 5:48.
Husbands should love their wives as Christ loved His people and gave Himself for her.  Eph 5:25.
Keep the commandments as Jesus kept the commandments.  John 14:15, 15:10.
Abide in Christ as Christ abides in us.  John 15:4.
Jesus is the “beginning and the end” (Rev 22:13) and Jesus is the beginning and end of our faith (Heb 12:2).
We are co-heirs with Christ of glory.  Rom 8:17.
Jesus gave his all and we must give up all things for Him.  Rom 8:32.
Jesus is called the “Lamb of God” (John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19) and so are His followers (John 10:1-18, 21:15-17)
Jesus washed the disciples’ feet (John 13:1-17) and so should we (John 13:14-17)
Jesus is the light of the world (John 1:4, 9, 8:12, 9:5) and so are we (Matt 5:14-16, Phil 2:14)
Jesus is the “firstborn” Luke 2:7, Rom 8:29, Col 1:15, 18, Heb 1:6, Rev 1:5, and we are to compose the church/assembly of the firstborn, Heb 12:23; see also Rom 8:23 & Rev 14:4 where we are also called first-fruits to God and the Lamb.
Jesus is our sacrifice of atonement and likened to a sacrificial lamb offered for us John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, Eph 5:2, 1 John 2:2, 4:10, Heb 10:10, 12, Rom 3:25, 1 Peter 1:19, etc.  Similarly, the life of a Christian is lived sacrificially for Christ Rom 12:1, Phil 2:17, Heb 13:15.
Jesus, by His sacrifice on the cross, reconciled sinners to God (Rom 5:10, Col 2:16, 1:20, 22, 2 Cor 5:19), and we must also be involved in the “ministry of reconciliation” (2 Cor 5:18, 19) as “ambassadors for Christ” (2 Cor 5:20).


Thank you, Dottard, for the outstanding answer--just what I was looking for! :-)

In the Hebrew text of Matthew 23:8-10 found in Shem Tov’s version, the term רַבָּנִים ("rabbanim" or "masters") appears in both verses 8 and 10, creating what might seem like redundancy. This repetition in Hebrew contrasts with the original Greek, which uses two distinct terms: διδάσκαλος (didáskalos) for "teacher" and καθηγητής (kathēgētēs) for "leader" or "guide." The distinction in Greek adds nuance, differentiating between a "teacher" and a "guide" in terms of spiritual authority.
However, Shem Tov’s Hebrew version, which links back to an ancient Greek text, presents this repetition of רַבָּנִים as a stylistic choice—something common in ancient Hebrew texts. In Hebrew, repetition is often used to reinforce a central idea. Here, the intent seems to be to emphasize that disciples should not seek authoritative titles, as there is only one "Master" (or "Rabbi") and "Father" in heaven to whom they should be accountable.
While the redundancy in Hebrew may seem to lack the nuanced distinctions present in Greek, it still effectively conveys the core message: disciples are to avoid titles that imply spiritual superiority. This simplification may be typical of Hebrew translations from that period, where exact distinctions from the Greek were not always preserved.

Interesting point! A similar situation seems to be present in several other passages. For example, the famous exchange between the resurrected Jesus and Peter using both agape and phileo as words for love while they were likely speaking in Aramaic.  Another example is why Simeon used the Greek word, rhomphaia in Luke 2:35, which was the only reference to this long, obsolescent sword in the New Testament outside of Revelation (it might have been a reference to Psalm 22).
